# Vue 3 Modal Comes Back With Old Data When Reopen

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I'm using Vue 3 and Vuex 4. When I open the modal, the main object (car) becomes equal to the default object, and those default values fill the modal's form. The codes down below are the simplified version.

Vuex module:

```
state: {
    car: {}
    defaults: {
        brand: "",
        color: "",
        value: ""
        ...
    }
},
actions: {
    fillTheCar(state, commit) {
        commit("SET_CAR", state.defaults)
    },
},
mutations: {
    SET_CAR(state, payload) {
        state.car = payload
    }
}
getters: {
    data(state) {
        return state.car    
    }
}
```

When I fill out any input fields, the "car" object is updated as it's supposed to be. When I closed the modal:

```
methods: {
    closeModal() {
        this.$store.commit("Cars/SET_CAR", {})
        // I have a different Vuex module to control all toggled items
        // such as sidebar, modals, header, etc.
        // I change modal visibility on there.
        this.$store.commit("Toggles/SET_VISIBILITY", {modal: false}
    }
}
```

My file structure is like so:

```
App.vue 
/ Components
  / Modal.vue
  / Input.vue
  / ...
/ Pages
  / Cars
    / Show.vue
    / Edit.vue
    / Create.vue
    / Delete.vue
    / CarModal.vue
```

When I go to "/cars" route, Show.vue is displayed in App.vue.

When I click "Create" button, Create.vue, which includes CarModal.vue and all functions related to creating a car, becomes visible.

CarModal.vue has all necessary form items for CRUD action and injects itself into /components/Modal.vue

```
//components/Modal.vue
<template>
    <teleport to="body">
        <slot name="header"></slot>
        <slot name="content"></slot>
        <slot name="actions"></slot>
    </teleport>
</template>
```

I hope those details will be enough to get help. Here is my problem:

If I fill out some inputs and close the modal, then reopen it, it comes back with data in the previously filled inputs, even though I make empty the car object when I close the modal. I tried the destroy Modal, CarModal, and Create files by using v-if. It didn't make any changes. I tried to set :key="Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000)" to containers on the same files and change the key randomly at the modal close. It didn't work too. I don't know any other option to reset the form. I hope someone can point out what I'm missing here. BTW, I'm sure the car object becomes empty when I close the modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe problem lies in your store

```js
actions: {
    fillTheCar(state, commit) {
        commit("SET_CAR", state.defaults)
    },
},
mutations: {
    SET_CAR(state, payload) {
        state.car = payload
    }
}
```

*When I open the modal, the main object (car) becomes equal to the default object, and those default values fill the modal's form*

So when you opening the modal, you are calling `fillTheCar` action which will in turn call mutation - result is, `state.car` points to the same object as `state.defaults`. So when you change something in the modal, you are actually changing properties of `state.defaults` too (should be easy check in Vue Dev Tools)

When closing modal, `this.$store.commit("Cars/SET_CAR", {})` will just set `state.car` to a new object but when you open it again, it will be again set to `state.defaults` (already modified from before)

**TLDR**

This is not Vue/Vuex issue but JavaScript usage one...

To set `state.car` to some defaults, instead of `commit("SET_CAR", state.defaults)` do `commit("SET_CAR", { ...state.defaults })` ...this will create new object with property values copied from `state.defaults` (assuming all properties are value types as strings, numbers etc. ie. not passed by reference)

Comment: It was an incredible rookie mistake I made. Yes, you're right, and your suggestion solved my issue. Thanks a lot.